# Published google script link with Google Sheet returning printing empty variable

Tags: json, function, google-apps-script, web-applications

Since I tend to ramble, first a short version and if you need more information read the long one.

**TL;DR**

Why is this:

```
function doGet(e) {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var jobsCreated = sheet.getRange(12,2).getValue();

Browser.msgBox(jobsCreated);

var params = JSON.stringify({number:jobsCreated});

return ContentService.createTextOutput(params);

}
```

returning this when I published as website and then open:
`{"number":""}`

when it should look more like this `{"number":2451}`

**Full Version:**

First of all, I learned to program back in uni for my Computer science degree (10 years ago) but since then I haven't done much programming so I am basically a newbie.

Now to the question. I have a very simple script that a created with the script editor from Google Sheets

```
function doGet(e) {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var jobsCreated = sheet.getRange(12,2).getValue();

Browser.msgBox(jobsCreated);

var params = JSON.stringify({number:jobsCreated});

return ContentService.createTextOutput(params);

}
```

First I get the sheet I am working on

Then I select a cell from that sheet

now if I use a msgBox to make sure that I have the right number and run the script, it works and it shows the message.

next, I format the variable as JSON and finally I just create a text output.

Now I deploy as Web app

- Execute as ME
- Anyone, even anonymous

And when I access the website I can only see this:
`{"number":""}`
If I change the code and give jobsCreated and static value it works fine

```
var jobsCreated = 100;
{"number":100}
```

So my conclusion is that the problem is with accessing the value of the cell when running the script from the published link compare to running it directly from the editor, but I have no idea how to fix this.

A little bit more information, i am trying to use this for a counter called Smiirl, i got most of the information from here
https://medium.com/@m_nebra/bootstrapping-your-company-counter-22f5d4bc7dd4

Comment: Have you republished a new version of the script after modification?

Comment: 2. Remove Browser.msgbox and try

Comment: I have republished with new versions, i am in version number 16 now with all the changes i have tried, and about the Browser.msgbox i have tried it without it too. I only put it there to check that i was getting something but then i tested it without

Comment: Try `console.log(jobsCreated)`. And borel view logs in stackdriver. You should save a new version ( create a new one v17) and then publish. Alternatively, just try the `/dev` url

Comment: @ITVHR see if my answer works for you.

Comment: @TheMaster i tried that and i got Stackdriver logs
Feb 21, 2020, 8:58:05 AM Debug 5000      (the value of the cell is 5000)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(Utilities.formatString('number: %s',SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(12,2).getValue());

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it didn't work. it was missing a parenthesis but i fixed that but the result i got was   number:

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the use of `JSON.stringify`

***In JSON, functions are not allowed as object values.***

The [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function will omit or change to `null` any functions from a JavaScript object.

#### That said, you can do the following:

```js
function doGet(e){
  
  // Get the value of the range
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var jobsCreated = sheet.getRange(12,2).getValue();
  
  // JSON Stringify it
  var params = JSON.stringify({"number" : number=jobsCreated});
  
  // Return JSON string
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(params);
  
}
```

#### Returns:

- `{"number":123}` if `jobsCreated` is the number 123, or
- `{"number":"Mangos"}` if `jobsCreated` is the string "Mangos".

See it the script deployed [here](https://script.googleusercontent.com/a/macros/egs-sbt074.eu/echo?user_content_key=ngs7GEliObyKjlUwQ4ILLHVRR9c_yK6c5OtEBe4ed2anFxxz-GeL1SvOChPpG-GBCfBDaVeOMYySIAQXdzLH-g1y_x1mB802m5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_nfVGVWXhpDIW-Bntt5LuLdcUp3BkGo8f68n4RAo2RJxsH7TsszZsxyIJoRaT9jBZxm0wJDXQpy6XTQUUJS-3xLXXDaPqwI0AMKS_dIjJZSI&lib=MdmqAgEDycMhRAEfrS9IbHV_gr41w1LbZ), and the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GTlrJbvGmsCL4k5dPdeDqCwPTmz9Diia9uCZSI_zNVo/edit) to play with.

---

#### *Note:*

*You should avoid using functions in JSON, the functions will lose their scope, and you would have to use eval() to convert them back into functions.*

---

Comment: First thanks for the reply. I tried it and it returns the same as the original.Also with the original version if i print param with the same Browser.msgBox it shows the correct string for params its just when I run the published script that doesnt work

Comment: I have no issues with the deployed script

Comment: Also to clarify the reason i am trying to get a JSON at the end is because i am trying to tie this with a device, a custom counter from Smiirl that only takes values in JSON form

Comment: that is why i am so frustrated, because i dont think i should get any issue either and it works fine when is a static number is only when using the published script with the value from the cell that it doesn't work

Comment: @ITVHR I left links to the web app, you can take a look, and the sheet + script

Comment: ok even weirder, i created a new Sheet, gave a number to cell 1 1 and tried the code again pointing to that, and it works... so i am not sure what was wrong with the other sheet

Comment: Did you test the web app I linked in the answer?

Comment: Yes i checked it and it works fine, it seems the issue is when the cell value comes from an add on (google analytics) that I am finding the problem

Comment: Check the frequency of GA refreshing your sheet, and try a Boolean check so you don't print empty values

Comment: `jobsCreated` is a number. I don't see how the issue is in JSON.stringify. op's script should work fine.

Comment: I only run the report once, I don't have it scheduled to refresh, at least at the moment. And I am very new to programming, about eh boolean check are you referring to .isBlank()? if I just print the value it does return something.

Comment: yes, Boolean as return True or False, so `isBlank()` is valid check. Ok, perhaps, try making a new question, sharing the steps to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

Ok as I replied to @Aerials, thank you again for your help btw. Seeing other codes that should work not working with my script, I decided to create a new sheet and script as a test and with the exact same code it works.

But now checking on it a little bit more, something that I didn't think it was a problem since it was getting the number without any problems. The cell it's being populated by a GoogleAnalytics add-on. Now when setting up the add-on again to get the information the script from the website returns an empty value again. SO it seems the issue is with the script getting the information from the sheet (only the published version) when its being populated by the add on